# Round time formatted time

Tags: javascript

I got the data and time difference in Hrs:Min.000000000000001. For example

```
00:04.533333333333333
```

Now I want to format/round it to HH:MM:SS, so it shows something like

```
00:04:53
```

What I tried is

```
formatted = 00:04.533333333333333;
formatted = Number(formatted.toFixed(2));
```

There is Type error message (formatted.toFixed is not a function).

Comment: are you sure, you want `00:04.53`? it could be with seconds `00:04:32` ...

Comment: I wonder how you got that far in your code, because `formatted = 00:04.533333333333333;` should return `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: Well, if `formatted = 00:04.533333333333333;` itself is valid JavaScript code is by pure chance.

Comment: If it is a normal time format `HH:mm:ss`, then you can split the string with `:`, round the last part and then join the parts with `:`

Comment: @NinaScholz, the time was in milliseconds, so the difference is the result. well, how to format it in 00:04:32? please.

Comment: var formatted = '00:04.533333333333333';
formatted = Number(formatted.split(":")[1]).toFixed(2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 with using `toFixed` and reassambling the string

```js
var time = '00:04.533333333333333',
    parts = time.split('.');

parts[1] = (+('0.' + parts[1])).toFixed(2).slice(2);
console.log(parts.join(':'));
```

Option 2 with treating the fraction part as part from 100 seconds as a minute

```js
var time = '00:04.533333333333333',
    parts = time.split('.');

parts[1] = Math.floor(('0.' + parts[1]) * 60);
console.log(parts.join(':'));
```

Comment: Thanks Nina , option 2 more precise, I think.